# Corda Account: Getting Account Info From Public Key Returns "Null"

Tags: corda

I am trying to get Account Info Object from the public key stored in the Anonymous Party using the following:

```
accountService.accountInfo(programCurrency.getPartner().getOwningKey()).getState().getData();
```

But everytime I am getting null. I checked the Anonymous party object coming from the vault query is not null when I am logging it and I get the following:

**Anonymous(DL5Z9Sv3285QANUNK5Vm6crWtFK2tE4QXUFoEoYuWH7ahm)**

I still cannot understand why its returning null.

P.S.: The account for which I am trying to get info is hosted on another node, but while creation I am sharing the Account Info whith other nodes using the: ShareAccountInfo() subflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the account was assigned a new public key that your node (the one that's querying using that public key) is not aware of; so although it has that account (because it was shared with it); it wasn't kept up to date with the new public keys that the account acquired.

Read [here](https://training.corda.net/libraries/accounts-lib/#passing-keys-around) about syncing keys; check their flow `SyncKeyMappingInitiator` which uses `SyncKeyMappingFlow` to sync the keys.

You can also read about syncing keys [here](https://medium.com/corda/cordas-accounts-tokens-making-blockchain-more-inclusive-for-everyone-3bf0c3993d41) (search `SyncKeyMappingFlow`).

Comment: So, just to clarify everytime I do a RequestKeyForAccount() i need to also call the SyncKeyMappingInitiator Flow?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that the same `UUID` of your `AccountInfo` will have many public keys which are stored in the node's database in a table (that maps the `UUID` to all associated public key), but it is possible (because your node is not the host of the account) that its mapping table doesn't have some public keys that were generated for that account (let's say your node is Node1, and there's a Host of the account, and Node2; if Node2 requested a new key for the account, the Host and Node2 will update their `UUID` to public key mapping with the new value, but Node1 won't).

Comment: So basically Host and Node2 will be aware that this public key belongs to the account, but Node1 won't (which is probably what happened in your case). When you call `SyncKeyMappingFlow`, the Host will send you all the public keys for that account.

Comment: Hey Adel, I tried syncing the keys but its still giving null. While looking deeper into the logs I found some errors like this: persistence.AbstractPartyToX500NameAsStringConverter. - Identity service unable to resolve AbstractParty: Anonymous(DLAWsssZsoZamcAqGxW8oAyX42jY6c96NJGrqLKhGEoB7L). Can this be the reason?

Comment: I'm not too sure, but I assume that the node that hosts the account shared the state where this account is a participant with another node (where the error is happening); if that's the case, did you also share the account with that node? Because the node that received the state (where the account is a participant) is not aware of the account, it has to be sent to it as well. Have a look at  [this flow](https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/workflows/flows/ShareStateAndSyncAccountsFlow.kt).

Comment: I am quiet sure I am sharing the accounts, its exactly same as [this flow](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Accounts/worldcupticketbooking/workflows/src/main/java/com/t20worldcup/flows/CreateAndShareAccountFlow.java)

Comment: Maybe add a flow test that insures that the account was shared with the node? Also you can turn on debug mode in your node (see [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/node-commandline.html#enabling-remote-debugging)) and put breakpoints in your code.

Comment: I dont know why the SyncKeyMapping flow was not working on looking into the db I found out that though it was sharing the AnonymousParties with other nodes but it wasn't mapping it with the external ids of the account.... the external id's mapped were entirely different. Ultimately the issue was resolved using the ShareStateAndSyncAccount Flow. Thanks for the help.